# What does this GDB output means?

Tags: gdb

I have a buffer of chars, when info locals I get this :

```
buf = "\310X\346\354\376\177\000\000E2\360\025\241\177\000\000pG\356\025\241\177\000\000\000\000\000\000\211\320\005\000\340G\356\025\241\177\000\000\000 \000\000\000\000\000\000 \247\244\025\241\177\000\000\000\243\341\021\000\000\000\000\030L\356\025\241\177\000\000W\220\244\025\241\177\000\000\032\000\000\000\000\000\000\000hJ\356\025\241\177\000\000hJ\356\025\241\177\000\000\241\005$\026"
```

I am confused how to interpret this output. I excepted pairs of hexa digits (2 hexa = 1 byte). How to read that ? It's not even decimal notation since some are greater than 256.

Comment: If `buf` is a character array, try `p *buf` and see what it outputs

Comment: Most characters are printables yes so I should recognize them, when trying your command I get (gdb) p *buf
$2 = -56 '\310'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am confused how to interpret this output.

By default, GDB prints unprintable characters in octal notation, so `\310` is `0xc8`. The first characters in your buffer are `0xc8 0x58 0xe6 0xec ...`.

It might be easier to interpret the buffer if it is printed as hex. Use `x/20xb buf` to examine the first 20 characters, or `p/x buf` to examine the entire buffer until terminating `NUL`.

Comment: I see, I expected it to display in hex by default as "usual" in other applications.